# Removing elements from collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've a product with multiple images.
When I delete an image from the product in my form, it's setting the product reference to NULL. But, the image still exists in the database for no reason.

I want to remove the image row from the database to. How can I do this?

My product entity

```
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"})
     * )
     */
    protected $images;

    ...

    /**
     * Get images.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Add a image to the product.
     *
     * @param Images
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function addImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $image->setProduct($this);
            $this->images->add($image);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $images
     */
    public function removeImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $image->setProduct(null);
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
        }
    }
```

Image entity

```
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Product", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $product;

...

/**
 * Allow null to remove association
 *
 * @param Product $product
 */
public function setProduct(Product $product = null)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

/**
 * Get product.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->product;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `cascade={"remove"}`, also I don't know exactly whether you have to define a cascade at @ORM\ManyToOne(..) side too (not only for the join column)

Comment: I tried it at the ManyToOne side. But it's not working. The other side has already cascade={"all"} defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is the orphanRemoval property (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)

"When using the orphanRemoval=true option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one."

So your OneToMany side should be like:

`@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)`